# How to type smiley face ASCII☺?

Tags: ascii, ascii-art

How to type smiley face ASCII ☺ ?

P.S  I copy pasted ☺ from a site. ☺

Comment: Have you googled "ascii art facebook"? Lots of advice there.

Comment: It's not included in the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set, though it is in the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the windows program `charmap`.

Just type `charmap` into the search box on the start menu (vista and 7) or select start->run and type in `charmap` (in 9x to XP).

Make sure the character set is set to `Unicode` in the dropdown in the lower half, and take your pick from the myriad of characters there.  You can then copy and paste the characters to your heart's content.

**NB:** Not all websites will support Unicode text and may filter it out or complain at you.

Answer (score 10):

Alt + 1 (on the number pad, make sure num lock is on)
☺

(alt+2 to make him black)
☻

Comment: Strangest thing! Smiley was practically at the beginning of the 437 code page all along, and we didn't use it till the 90s when people invented the colon-bracket thing...

Answer (score 8):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order.

Comment: How can I enter this in Facebook?

Comment: You don't. You enter it in your operating system.

Comment: Unfortunately, Ctrl-Shift-U appears to be specific to GNOME (GTK2) programs.